# how to use looping in view codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, loops

I had a problem to display data by rows of columns, I have several times tried still confused. why always fill in row number one, I wanted to show one line of the sample data in row number one IVB, IVA in row number two and further, what should I change?

this pictures
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m83zg.png)

my controller

```
public function print_data()
{

    $data['data'] = $this->M_rekap->gol();
    $this->load->view('rekap/print3',$data);
}
```

my view

```
 foreach($data as $row)
{?>
  <tr class="xl6332140" height="5" style="mso-height- source:userset;height:3.75pt">
  <td height="5" class="xl8332140" style="height:3.75pt">&nbsp; 1</td>
  <td class="xl9732140">&nbsp; <?php echo $row->GOLONGAN; ?></td>
  <td class="xl8732140">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="xl8732140">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="xl9832140">&nbsp;</td>
 <td class="xl9832140">&nbsp;</td>
 <td class="xl9832140">&nbsp;</td>
 <td class="xl8732140">&nbsp;</td>
 <td class="xl8732140">&nbsp;</td>
 <td class="xl8732140">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?php 
} ?>
```

my model

```
public function gol()
{ 
 $query = $this->db->select('GOLONGAN')->order_by('GOLONGAN','DESC')
                  ->get('golongan');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: what format are you getting your data back? can you share your screenshot of dump or print_r($data). do format it with a < pre>

Comment: can you click this on word this pictures

Answer (score 1):

try this in model

```
        public function gol()
    { 
     $query = $this->db->select('*')->order_by('GOLONGAN','DESC')
                      ->get('golongan');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
   {
        return $query->result();
    }
 else {
        return false;
    }
    }
```

try this in view

```
    <?php 
 $i=1;
 foreach($data as $row):?>

     <tr class="xl6332140" height="5" style="mso-height- source:userset;height:3.75pt">
          <td height="5" class="xl8332140" style="height:3.75pt">&nbsp; <?php echo $i++; ?></td>
          <td class="xl9732140">&nbsp; <?php echo $row->GOLONGAN; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: are you use this query in your model?

Comment: if find solution accept the ans and voted thats other can find help.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Creating a table needs two things 
   1. Column Names 
   2. Data to fill

You have fetched data from your model in $data array

Create Table headers like

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td> Sr. # </td>
  <td> Column-1 </td>
  <td> Column-2 </td>
  <td> Column-3 </td>
  <td> Column-4 </td>
</tr>
```

Then loop through your array and print the data

```
<?php
$count=1;
foreach($data as $row) { <?php
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $count;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[index1];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[index2];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[index3];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[index4];?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: if it is not one of its data will appear sideways instead, what if the data appeared to bottom?

Comment: what do you mean "one of its data" . Do you mean , you are not sure about number of columns the data will fit into or the number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this?

```
<?php
if ($data) {
    echo '<tr class="xl6332140" height="5" style="mso-height- source:userset;height:3.75pt">';
    foreach ($data as $row) {            
?>
       <td class="xl9732140">&nbsp; <?php echo $row->GOLONGAN; ?></td>
<?php            
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: i want the data to bottom not sideway

Comment: @MelvinArioWitama can you provide a diagram or picture on how you want your table will look like?